# Run VBA Excel script on an Excel document from an Access subroutine

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have a section of code to find the bottom right cell, that runs in excel, and I want to be able to run it through an Access subroutine, which will return the cell coordinates (Ex.: J17). However I'm not that familiar with Access and am unsure of how to translate the code.

```
Sub FindLast_Message()

MsgBox FindLast(3)

End Sub

Function FindLast(lRowColCell As Long, _
                Optional sSheet As String, _
                Optional sRange As String)
'Find the last row, column, or cell using the Range.Find method
'lRowColCell: 1=Row, 2=Col, 3=Cell

Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long
Dim wsFind As Worksheet
Dim rFind As Range

'Default to ActiveSheet if none specified
On Error GoTo ErrExit

If sSheet = "" Then
    Set wsFind = ActiveSheet
Else
    Set wsFind = Worksheets(sSheet)
End If

'Default to all cells if range no specified
If sRange = "" Then
    Set rFind = wsFind.Cells
Else
    Set rFind = wsFind.Range(sRange)
End If

On Error GoTo 0

Select Case lRowColCell

    Case 1 'Find last row
        On Error Resume Next
        FindLast = rFind.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=rFind.Cells(1), _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Row
        On Error GoTo 0

    Case 2 'Find last column
        On Error Resume Next
        FindLast = rFind.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=rFind.Cells(1), _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Column
        On Error GoTo 0

    Case 3 'Find last cell by finding last row & col
        On Error Resume Next
        lRow = rFind.Find(What:="*", _
                       After:=rFind.Cells(1), _
                       LookAt:=xlPart, _
                       LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                       SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                       SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                       MatchCase:=False).Row
        On Error GoTo 0

        On Error Resume Next
        lCol = rFind.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=rFind.Cells(1), _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Column
        On Error GoTo 0

        On Error Resume Next
        FindLast = wsFind.Cells(lRow, lCol).Address(False, False)
        'If lRow or lCol = 0 then entire sheet is blank, return "A1"
        If Err.Number > 0 Then
            FindLast = rFind.Cells(1).Address(False, False)
            Err.Clear
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0

End Select

Exit Function

ErrExit:

MsgBox "Error setting the worksheet or range."

End Function
```

---

Below is the section of Access code where I need to coordinate this with. The 'J72' should be the bottom right cell coordinate as returned by the previous code.

```
Sub Format_Excel_Workbook(workbook_path As String, worksheet_name As String, myRows As Integer, myColumns As Integer)
'==============================================================================
Dim objExcelApp As Object
Dim xlWbk As Object
'==============================================================================

Dim x, y As String

x = "B2"
y = "J72"
Z = x & ":" & y

'==============================================================================
Set objExcelApp = New Excel.Application

objExcelApp.Workbooks.Open (workbook_path)

objExcelApp.Worksheets("t_DATA").Columns.AutoFit

objExcelApp.Worksheets("t_DATA").Range(x).Select

objExcelApp.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

objExcelApp.Worksheets("t_DATA").Range(Z).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

objExcelApp.Worksheets("t_DATA").Range(Z).VerticalAlignment = xlTop

objExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Close (True)

Set objExcelApp = Nothing
'==============================================================================

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to change the parameters of your `FindLast()` function to objects instead of strings:

```
Function FindLast(lRowColCell As Long, _
                  Optional sSheet As Excel.Worksheet, _
                  Optional sRange As Excel.Range)
```

From Excel, you could call this function like this:

```
FindLast(3, , FindLast(3, , ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A3:E7")))
```

In the function you have to change those parts where the parameters sSheet and sRange are used: Simply use the provided objects instead of creating them from the strings.

With the function changed this way you can easily transport it to other host applications like Access, because the caller of the function defines the objects on which the function should operate, not the function itself.

From Access you could invoke the function like this:

```
FindLast(3, , objExcelApp.Worksheets("t_DATA").Range(Z))
```